# Can I deploy a svelte-kit app on php hosting without nodejs?

Tags: server-side-rendering, svelte, sveltekit

I am familiar with svelte.js for client side wherein client and server are disconnected and all communication is via AJAX calls. However, I have a question whether shared hosting without node installation can deploy a sveltekit app?

Any comments are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Yes and no. You can serve static sveltekit pages generated with `@sveltejs/adapter-static`. If you want SSR or to use server side load functions, endpoint, or any other 'backend' feature of sveltekit you will need to use a different adapter. For that, you will need `@sveltejs/adapter-node`, or another adapter. For supported environments see [this page of the docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapters#supported-environments). So yes, you will need a javascript runtime (probably nodejs) to use all of sveltekit's features.

Comment: Just to build on Caleb's accurate answer, `adapter-static` I feel is a bit of misnomer, your pages can still call and retrieve data from remote endpoints, it's just that those endpoints will not be part of your app, but rather be provided by 3rd-party APIs or by a separately deployed backend.

Comment: So, API routes can be made in php backend. Then what is the advantage of svelte-kit over svelte in that case? Does that mean that API backend and server hosting the frontend will have to be necessarily different?

Comment: SvelteKit is to Svelte what NextJS is to React or what NuxtJS is to Vue, if you're familiar with any of these. In either of these pairings, on one side you have a frontend framework, on the other you have a more complete solution that offers routing, ssr and the ability to serve endpoints, but also the ability to build into a static deploy.

Comment: Thanks! SPA build from svelte loads all of bundle together and then does client side rendering. I have a situation where a preexistent backend in PHP (Slim4) exists. So, if I use  ```adapter-static```, I loose SSR. But will sveltekit give me any advantage in terms of faster loads and SEO?

Comment: For SEO I would be inclined to say yes since for instance you'll be able to leverage dynamic page names (the `/routes/foo/[bar]` syntax) giving you more meaningful URLs -and that's just one example. Using layouts (and sub-layouts) is also better for handling shared elements across your pages, etc. Overall, I consider there are many advantages to using Kit over regular Svelte. Also, if at some point you decide to integrate your backend into the project, having your frontend already built with Kit will make the transition a lot easier.

Comment: My best advice would be to give Kit a go, you'll find you can pretty much copy your components across from your Svelte project, and all you'll have to do is build your `/routes` tree, define what your pages are and how they work together, and decide which component(s) go(es) into which page(s).

Comment: Also, because each page will have its own JS bundle and scoped CSS, the payloads tend to be smaller (= better performance). Page-scoped CSS does not prevent you from using global CSS on top, if you so desire.

Comment: See example how use adapter-static https://github.com/StagnantIce/sveltekit_php